# Count in XQuery giving strange results

Tags: xml, xquery

I'm trying to count how many trips have been taken to California within two dates

I have the current XQuery that is as follows:

```
for $x in doc("triptracker.xml")/data/cities/city,
  $y in doc("triptracker.xml")/data/trips/trip
let $date as xs:date := xs:date($y/date)
where $x/cityName = $y/cityName and $x/state = "CA"  and 
$date gt xs:date("2003-01-01") and $date lt xs:date("2006-12-31")
return <Result>Trips to California: {count($y)}</Result>
```

Which gives me the result set

```
<Result>Trips to California: 1</Result>
<Result>Trips to California: 1</Result>
<Result>Trips to California: 1</Result>
<Result>Trips to California: 1</Result>
<Result>Trips to California: 1</Result>
```

Instead of just giving me a count of 5

Here is the type of XML data being give for trip and city

```
<trips>
    <trip>
        <ssn>123-20-4567</ssn>
        <cityName>Tucson</cityName>
        <date>2001-08-11</date>
    </trip>
</trips>
<cities>
    <city>
        <cityName>Houston</cityName>
        <state>TX</state>
        <location>
            <latitude>29.76045</latitude>
            <longitude>-95.369784</longitude>
        </location>
    </city>
</cities>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I ended up noticing that by using the fors, I could never get only 1 count so I revised it using let

```
let $x := doc("triptracker.xml")/data/cities/city[state = "CA"],

$y := doc("triptracker.xml")/data/trips/trip[cityName=$x/cityName 
and xs:date(date) gt xs:date("2003-01-01")  
and xs:date(date) lt xs:date("2006-12-31")]

return <Result>Trips to California: {count($y)}</Result>
```

Comment: Correct. The return clause of a "for" expression is evaluated once for every value of the "in" expression (or once for every combination if there are multiple "for" clauses. Therefore there is no way of doing aggregation within the return clause - and no need to do so, because if you are going to aggregate over a sequence then you don't need to iterate over the sequence.